# Want to add horizontal spacing between cards of CardView in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

Want to add Spacing between the cards of CardView without using cardUseCompatPadding, How can i achieve that ?

Comment: You can use _padding_. Further detail show screenshot.

Comment: why don't you want to use cardUseCompatPadding??????

Comment: on use of cardUseCompatPadding if i am swipping left/right the background doesn't take that padding and it comes with more height and width

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set Padding on rows so that all the items set spacing between each items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFF"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

// here your views

</LinearLayout>
```

or, Use like this by java to saperate items

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());  
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    int spacingInPixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));
```

Class

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private int space;

public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
    this.space = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                           RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = space;
    outRect.right = space;
    outRect.bottom = space;

    // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
    if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0) {
        outRect.top = space;
    } else {
        outRect.top = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are using data binding, you may prefer to inspect `<Space />` component **in your list item for horizontal `RecyclerView` spacing**

like below;

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="data"
        type="com.foo.Entity" />

    <variable
        name="position"
        type="int" />

    <import type="android.view.View" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="6dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:visibility="@{position == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_border">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@{data.text}"
            android:textColor="#6b778d"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            tools:text="Foo" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And you will see;

[image]